# C# MySQL - Difference between 2 queries

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

im working on a project and for the next part I will need to compare the results of 2 queries.

Scenario:
in a table I keep all the players in the team.
in another table are only the ones you the coach called for the match.

I want to know which players were left out

What is the best approach for me to take?

Could i use something like

```
    (Query for Selecting all players)
    EXCEPT
    (Query for Selecting the ones called by the coach)
```

Tables

ALL PLAYERS

```
   Number | Name
   ------ | ------
   23     | john 
   24     | Mario
```

Selected PLAYERS

```
   Number | Name
   ------ | ------
   23     | john
```

I want it to give the result that mario is missing from the selected players table

Comment: Please add tables with data and expected result. Makes it a lot easier to understand what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `NOT EXISTS`

```
select * from all_players p1
where not exists
(select 1 from players p2
where p1.number=p2.number
and p1.name=p2.name
--  and -- You can add other columns here
) t
```

Using `LEFT JOIN`

```
select p1.* from all_players p1
left join players p2
on p1.number=p2.number
and p1.name=p2.name
-- and p1.last_name=p2.last_name --add other columns
where 
(p2.number is null 
 and p2.name is null 
 -- and p2.last_name is null --add other columns
)
```

Using IN, if there is same key to be matched

```
select * From all_players p
where number not in (select number from players)
```

Comment: im gonna make the same question i did to the others

ok that seems to be what im looking for but in my case, lets say the last name of the players are in another column, so that 2 johns can exist with different last names how do i compare the now 4 fields

i wanna compare by the first and second name combined

Comment: YES! The left join method worked thanks! Haven't tried the other ones since i already have What i need. 

If anyone tries and succeeds with the other methods comment

Answer (score 0):

User this u can get your result

`Select players from players_table where player not in (select coach_selected_player from coach_selected_player_table)`

Comment: ok that seems to be what im looking for but in my case, lets say the last name of the players are in another column, so that 2 johns can exist with different last names how do i compare the now 4 fields

Comment: then add another condition like `or` or `and` and compare another field too